# 'git pull' does not update changes from remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have setup my local branch to track remote branch.

when I do `git pull`, it said 'Already up-to-date'.

But when I do `git log`, the latest checkin is on Dec 21, 2012'.

And when I do `git log remotes/branch1` (the branch I am trying to track), the latest checkin is on Jan 7, 2013'.

Why I don't get changes check in? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to set up tracking. Use `git branch --set-upstream remotes/branch1`. Although your remote doesn't look ok. It should be `origin/branch`.